# How to substact a list of dictionaries (from an API) in a for loop to a new list

Tags: python, api

Here's what I've tried: I've made a function that returns all the product keys of every transaction (in a given time) from an API. I pass these key's in a for loop to info to get more specific data of every transaction in list of dictionaries and save the outcome to attrib. when I print attrib it returns just the last item, but if I print attrib inside the for loop it returns all items. How do I save all the data permanently, so I can access it by indexing the items in the list?

```
def product_id():
    transactions = degiro.transactions(datetime(2020, 7, 30), datetime.now())
    pid = [dic["productId"] for dic in transactions]
    return pid


attrib = []
products = [num for num in product_id()]
for i in range(len(products)):
    info = degiro.product_info(products[i])
    attrib = ({k: v for k, v in info.items()})
print(pretty_json(attrib))
```

[Click here](https://pypi.org/project/degiroapi/) fo a link to the API

Comment: I've tried that. It returns: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'
"

Comment: Because attrib is a list.. Also there's no need for the comprehension if so `attrib.update(info)` is all you need

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. ```attrib.append(info)``` seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

````
    transactions = degiro.transactions(datetime(2020, 7, 30), datetime.now())
    pid = [dic["productId"] for dic in transactions]
    return pid


print(product_id())

attrib = []
products = [num for num in product_id()]
for i in range(len(products)):
    info = degiro.product_info(products[i])
    attrib.append(info)
print(pretty_json(attrib))```
````